# Adding directline voice to waterfall dialog bot using Microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, chatbot, speech-to-text, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to add the ability for using the direct line voice channel in my dialog bot. I was reading the tutorial from Microsoft on how to do this, but they just use the echo bot. I want to be able to use the dialog bot and return the voice. I have already created a speech resource in azure, as well as implemented the direct line speech channel in the bot resource on azure. Has any one been successful in adding voice to a dialog bot? I was reading that there would be prompt options for speech, but I can not find that property in my PromptOptions object.

Comment: Just clarifying, are you interested in Direct Line Speech or Cognitive Services Speech? Both have slightly different implementations.

Comment: I actually am interested in both.  I have a direct line speech channel enabled, but I couldn't get the microphone on the webchat in my azure resource group.  The ultimate goal is to find a way to have a user be able to use their microphone.  Possible methods they can use is via Microsoft Teams. Cortana, or via DIrect line.

Answer (score 1):

How speech is configured depends on the type you mean to use, which also means possibly updating your bot as well as the client you are using.

A quick note about clients (i.e. channels) - the channel is what determines whether speech is supported or not. For instance:

- Outside of designing a calling bot, STT (speech-to-text) is not supported in Teams.
- Cortana is no longer a public offering and is now only accessible via an Enterprise account.
- Web Chat, which is built on top of Direct Line and has DL Speech integrated into it, supports both CS and DL Speech

  - It's important to note that DL Speech is its own channel separate from Direct Line, therefore it requires additional code in your bot. The samples located at [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples) include this code, by default.
  - Custom-built clients using either DL or DL Speech would require you to build in functionality that would allow Speech to work.
- Other channels, such as Telegram, Slack, etc., are channel specific and, of course, don't rely on CS or DL Speech for enabling. A custom-built third-party channel supporting speech would require you to consult that channel's docs for implementation.

---

Regarding DL Speech, you need to add / update your bot's `index.js` code to include the following:

```js
[...]

// Catch-all for errors.
const onTurnErrorHandler = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights. See https://aka.ms/bottelemetry for telemetry 
    //       configuration instructions.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${ error }`);

    // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${ error }`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    );

    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug.');
    await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.');
};

// Set the onTurnError for the singleton BotFrameworkAdapter.
adapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

[...]

// Listen for Upgrade requests for Streaming.
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
    // Create an adapter scoped to this WebSocket connection to allow storing session data.
    const streamingAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
        appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
        appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
    });
    // Set onTurnError for the BotFrameworkAdapter created for each connection.
    streamingAdapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

    streamingAdapter.useWebSocket(req, socket, head, async (context) => {
        // After connecting via WebSocket, run this logic for every request sent over
        // the WebSocket connection.
        await myBot.run(context);
    });
});
```

And, then in Web Chat, you would pass in the following. (You can reference the below code in this DL Speech [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/03.speech/a.direct-line-speech). Also, note that you will want to update the "fetch" address to an API of your own for generating a token.):

```js
[...]

const fetchCredentials = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot-streaming.azurewebsites.net/speechservices/token', {
      method: 'POST'
});

if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch authorization token and region.');
}

const { region, token: authorizationToken } = await res.json();
    return { authorizationToken, region };
};

// Create a set of adapters for Web Chat to use with Direct Line Speech channel.
const adapters = await window.WebChat.createDirectLineSpeechAdapters({
    fetchCredentials
});

// Pass the set of adapters to Web Chat.
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
        ...adapters
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
);

[...]
```

Here are some addition resources to help you better understand DL Speech:

- [Use Direct Line Speech in your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) - Doc only demonstrates c# implementation...they need to be updated.
- [Connect a bot to Direct Line Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directlinespeech?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- [Add speech to messages with the Bot Connector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-text-to-speech?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) - Be sure to READ THIS. It will help mitigate speech errors that generate when your bot isn't configured to respond correctly to the DL Speech channel.
- [Using Direct Line Speech](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/DIRECT_LINE_SPEECH.md) - Web Chat docs

---

Regarding CS Speech, you need to have an active [Cognitive Services subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-services/). Once you have your speech service setup in Azure, you use the subscription key to generate the token used for enabling CS Speech (you can also reference this Web Chat [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/03.speech/b.cognitive-speech-services-js). Not changes in your bot are necessary for enabling. (Again, you will want to set up an API for generating a token as best practice is to NOT include any keys in the HTML. This is what I do in this example for getting a DL token):

```js
let authorizationToken;
let region = '<<SPEECH SERVICES REGION>>';

const response = await fetch( `https://${ region }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<<SUBSCRIPTION KEY>>'
  }
} );
if ( response.status === 200 ) {
  authorizationToken = await response.text(),
    region
} else {
  console.log( 'error' )
}

const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory( {
  authorizationToken,
  region
} );

const res = await fetch( 'http://localhost:3500/directline/token', { method: 'POST' } );
const { token } = await res.json();

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( {
      token: token
    } ),
    webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory,
  },
  document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
);
```

Additional resources:

- [Using Cognitive Services Speech Services](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/SPEECH.md) - Web Chat docs

---

Hope of help!